# Ansible playbook starting with large forked host list, but spawning serial tasks for smaller subsets of hosts

Tags: ansible, ansible-tower

I'm using Ansible 2.9 and AWX 11. I have a fleet of servers, some of which can be logically segmented by a tag that follows a pattern like `GUID_1234567890`. There is an arbitrary number of servers represented by each unique `GUID_*` tag. In addition to the `GUID_*` tag, a server will be tagged with either `foo` or `bar`.

In more concrete terms, I have 2,000 servers, 1,000 of which are tagged with 80 unique `GUID_*` tags. Within each of those 80 unique `GUID_*` groups of servers, I have to restart the servers tagged with `foo`, but not the servers tagged with `bar`. Furthermore, I have to reboot the `foo` servers serially if they have the same `GUID_*` tag.

I can launch a playbook with a host pattern like this: `hosts: GUID_*:&foo` and get all of the `GUID_` tagged `foo` hosts. However, if the playbook's `serial:` option is anything except `1`, foo servers will be restarted in parallel, most likely multiple foo servers within the same `GUID_` tag group. When performed serially, the playbook can take upwards of a day to complete. I'd like to use Ansible's forking to run a fork of a playbook for each of the 80 groups of `GUID_*` hosts, but each fork must call a playbook that itself runs as `serial:1` against the `foo` servers.

Is there a way to start with large set of hosts, but then create parallel workers that execute `serial: 1` playbooks for a subset of hosts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to achieve the goal in a single playbook. A dedicated playbook for each group is needed if you want to process the groups in parallel. Use Ansible to create the code.

**"*Smaller subsets of hosts*"**

Given the inventory to simplify the testing

```yaml
test_01
test_02
test_03
test_04
test_05
test_06

[GUID_01]
test_01
test_02
test_03

[GUID_02]
test_04
test_05
test_06

[foo]
test_01
test_02
test_04
test_05
srvX

[bar]
test_03
test_06
srvY
```

Create a dictionary of all *GUID_** and a list of hosts both in particular *GUID_x* and *foo* groups. For example

```yaml
- hosts: GUID_*:&foo
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        my_groups: "{{ my_groups|default({})|
                       combine({item: my_hosts|dict2items|
                                      selectattr('value', 'eq', item)|
                                      map(attribute='key')|list}) }}"
      loop: "{{ my_guids|unique }}"
      vars:
        my_guids: "{{ ansible_play_hosts_all|
                      map('extract', hostvars, 'group_names')|
                      map('select', 'match', 'GUID')|
                      map('first')|flatten }}"
        my_hosts: "{{ dict(ansible_play_hosts_all|zip(my_guids)) }}"
      run_once: true
    - debug:
        var: my_groups
      run_once: true
```

gives

```yaml
  my_groups:
    GUID_01:
    - test_01
    - test_02
    GUID_02:
    - test_04
    - test_05
```

---

The same dictionary can be created without [patterns](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_patterns.html#patterns-targeting-hosts-and-groups)

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        my_groups: "{{ my_groups|default({})|
                       combine({item: groups[item]|
                                      intersect(groups['foo'])}) }}"
      loop: "{{ groups|select( 'match', 'GUID')|list }}"
      run_once: true
```

---

Q: **"*Create parallel workers that execute serial: 1 playbooks for a subset of hosts.*"**

A: Use Ansible templates to create the code. For example, given the role

```yaml
shell> cat roles/reboot/tasks/main.yml
- command: date "+%H:%M:%S"
  register: result
- debug:
    msg: "{{ result.stdout }} {{ inventory_hostname }} Reboot"
- command: sleep 3
- command: date "+%H:%M:%S"
  register: result
- debug:
    msg: "{{ result.stdout }} {{ inventory_hostname }} Ready"
```

The templates

```yaml
shell> cat templates/my_hosts.j2
{{ lookup('file', 'hosts') }}

# ---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Groups for my_wrapper. See template my_hosts.j2

{% for group,hosts in my_groups.items() %}
[my_{{ group }}]
{% for host in hosts %}
{{ host }}
{% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

```yaml
shell> cat templates/my_pb.j2
- hosts: my_{{ item }}
  gather_facts: false
  serial: 1
  roles:
    - reboot
```

```yaml
shell> cat templates/my_wrapper.j2
#!/bin/bash
{% for group,hosts in my_groups.items() %}
nohup ansible-playbook -i my_hosts my_pb_{{ group }}.yml &
{% endfor %}
```

and the playbook

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        my_groups: "{{ my_groups|default({})|
                       combine({item: groups[item]|
                                      intersect(groups['foo'])}) }}"
      loop: "{{ groups|select( 'match', 'GUID')|list }}"
      run_once: true
    - block:
        - template:
            src: my_hosts.j2
            dest: my_hosts
        - template:
            src: my_wrapper.j2
            dest: my_wrapper.sh
            mode: "a+x"
        - template:
            src: my_pb.j2
            dest: "my_pb_{{ item }}.yml"
          loop: "{{ my_groups.keys()|list }}"
      run_once: true
      delegate_to: localhost
```

create the files with the code

```yaml
shell> cat my_hosts

   ...

# ---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Groups for my_wrapper. See template my_hosts.j2

[my_GUID_01]
test_01
test_02

[my_GUID_02]
test_04
test_05
```

```sh
shell> cat my_wrapper.sh
#!/bin/bash
nohup ansible-playbook -i my_hosts my_pb_GUID_01.yml &
nohup ansible-playbook -i my_hosts my_pb_GUID_02.yml &
```

```yaml
shell> cat my_pb_GUID_01.yml 
- hosts: my_GUID_01
  gather_facts: false
  serial: 1
  roles:
    - reboot

shell> cat my_pb_GUID_02.yml 
- hosts: my_GUID_02
  gather_facts: false
  serial: 1
  roles:
    - reboot
```

Then, running the wrapper gives

```yaml
shell> grep msg nohup.out 
    "msg": "13:03:51 test_01 Reboot"
    "msg": "13:03:51 test_04 Reboot"
    "msg": "13:03:56 test_01 Ready"
    "msg": "13:03:56 test_04 Ready"
    "msg": "13:03:58 test_02 Reboot"
    "msg": "13:03:58 test_05 Reboot"
    "msg": "13:04:04 test_02 Ready"
    "msg": "13:04:04 test_05 Ready"
```

Comment: Wow! That's intense. You've forgotten more about Ansible than I could ever know. I'm going to stew in this tome you've written, and figure out what I didn't know, and see if I can iterate on it to somehow remove the need for a shell script. I've got to get this automated for another team that doesn't have shell access to the Ansible host. It might not be possible, but I need more evidence of that before I can change the scope of the project. I'll check back with an update when I know more.

Comment: I'm afraid it's not possible to remove the need for a shell script. The utility *ansible-playbook* is not able to run playbooks in parallel.  That's the spirit. Only [import_playbook](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/import_playbook_module.html) is available. Btw, I'd prefer to [keep it that way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle).

Comment: For the record. [I would like to run playbooks parallel. Is it possible ?](https://groups.google.com/g/ansible-project/c/9RVQ6w6uTRM).